# java.awt.print.PrinterException: Paper's imageable height is too small

Tags: java, printing

Im new to java and trying to print a pdf file using the following code but, I keep getting the above expetion. Can you help me soving it?

This is my code

```
private void printMergedFile(String printerName, String job, String fileName) throws IOException, PrinterException  
{
    PrintService[] service = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices(); // list of printers          
    DocPrintJob docPrintJob = null;
    PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(fileName);

    int count = service.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (service[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(printerName )) {
            docPrintJob = service[i].createPrintJob();
            i = count;
        }
    }


    pjob.setPrintService(docPrintJob.getPrintService());
    pjob.setJobName(job);
    pjob.print();
    doc.silentPrint(pjob);  
}
```

Tx